# Sql query to get top customer according to joining date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `"Customers"`.

It has some columns `"customerid","CreatedDate"`

`CreatedDate` is a joining date of customer.

Now I want to get top `20` customers that joined first in current year.

Means if 25 customer joined in January and 30 customer joined in February, than I want to get first 20 customers that join in January.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select top 20 * 
from customers
where year(createddate) = 2013
order by createddate
```

Comment: Thanks @Juergen, It is working fine, but I also want to get number of months, if we remove the where condition, means if anyone joined in 1 January 2011 than, answer is 34 months from joining date to current date.

Answer (score -1):

select cust_name,count(cust_name) no_of_orders
from
your_table
group by
cust_name
order by 2 desc